# is happens before i.e hb(x,y) not same as hb(y,x)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-memory-model, happens-before

Acceptable answers after looking at answers, comments and [jls-17.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2)

1) anti-symmetric property holds like pointed by -  user3707125

2) the hb relationship between locks is actually between unlocking and locking
hb(ul, l) which is not same as hb(l, ul).  Hinted by - shmosel
From JSL -

> An unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor.

3) and reasonable explanation of hb by james-large

---

**Actual question was:**

The java memory model(JMM) describes happens before relationships between several actions. If "x" and "y" are two actions with h(x,y) relation between them. JMM also states that implementations (compiler, run time or hardware) are free to re-order these executions if they achieve the same result as executing "x" and then "y" sequentially.

So i think that,

```
hb(x,y) != hb(y,x)
```

Am I right?  Or did I miss something?

**Update:**
Also for actions which involve locks how can a hb relation be established. As the event of locking by different threads can not be defined by program order, and is so just not deterministic and depends on several factors like instructions and scheduler etc.
So between two locking actions  -  l1 and l2 how to define the relationship hb(l1, l2) or hb(l2, l1). Seems both are acceptable. In this case both seems equal.
 **l1 and l2 are locking actions on same Object.**  l1 and l2 are not locks

**Clarification** (based on comments):
Locking actions are definitely mutually exclusive when locking is to be done on same Object by different threads.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before - "Like all strict partial orders, the happened-before relation is transitive, irreflexive and **antisymmetric**"

Comment: Why would they be the same? If *x* happens before *y*, obviously *y* doesn't happen before *x*.

Comment: i see that in general sense you both are right as pointed in wiki too - hb is antisymmetric. But there will many particular cases in general and in  JMM actions also for which this makes no difference, say locks as actions. There is only relationship that gets established between locks but not order. Hopefully i am right.

Comment: I'm also confused as to what's being asked here - of course `hb(x,y)` is not the same guarantee as `hb(y,x)`.

Comment: looking at particular case of lock order - hb(l1, l2) or  hb(l2, l1) . I updated the question too. thx for your response. But my question now is for a subset the anti-symmetric property might not hold as pointed. Right??

Comment: Now it sounds like you're asking if locks are mutually exclusive, which they are by definition. But that has little to do with the *happens-before* relationship.

Comment: shmosel, no my point is not about mutex.  **"Locks on same object from different threads are definitely mutex"** . The point is the order of locking can not be established just by program order. So how to define the order - hb(l1, l2) or hb(l2, l1)

Comment: Neither, because there **is no** *happens-before* guarantee for lock acquisition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the implementation is allowed to reorder operations, but only within reasonable limits.  The *happens before* relationships defined in the Java Language Specification (JLS) are there specifically to define the limits of what can be reordered.

If the JLS says that x happens before y, that means that the implementation is *not* allowed to do any reordering that would create the appearance of y happening before x.

Comment: there seems to be actions where the order just seems to not matter. Updated the question to reflect same. thx.